# Ошибка в подкачке данных у Composera

Tags: php, ssl, composer

Цель: подкачать данные.
При команде

> sudo composer install

выдает вот это

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The "https://asset-packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be     
downloade  
d: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                 
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol          
Failed to enable crypto                                                      
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Если же пишу просто

> composer install

выкидывает это

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The "https://asset-packagist.org/p/bower- 
asset/typeahead.js/ccc9e3f63e62506  
5e2dd381c4ab9c2ed3ba8a73f41393a07ee89402872d43386.json" file could not 
be d  
ownloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:         
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol          
Failed to enable crypto                                                      
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
composer show -p -vvv | grep ssl смотри что там
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в прокси. Отключите прокси.
Отключение для linux (Введите в командную строку)

```
export https_proxy=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
export http_proxy=
export HTTP_PROXY=
export https_proxy=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
```